# How do I add a form to a WordPress page?

Tags: cognito-forms

When trying to place the form onto a page I get this pop up message:

> #### No key present
>
> Please click on the "Cognito Forms" link in the menu on the left and log in to register this plug-in with your account.

I have sent a message to support, but they don't seem to find the time to answer me. I was under the impression that Cognito Forms could be used with Worpress.org … Am I wrong?

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Could you confirm when you submitted your support ticket? We do not have any outstanding tickets at this time but our response may have been blocked by your email provider. We apologize for the delay and are happy to help.

Comment: No it did not, as a matter of fact, after I submitted my ticket, I got a pop-up message saying "thank you for your submission, we will work on this for our next release."

Comment: @Nicholas Gasque. I submitted the ticket last week, 08/22/14, I doubt it was even looked at as I got a pop-up message saying "thank you for your submission, we will work on this for our next release."

I just sent a second submission and got the same pop-up message again.

Comment: I've confirmed within our support system that we did receive both of your submissions and we responded to both tickets during our regular support hours. Unfortunately it seems you weren't receiving the responses, so again we are sorry you've been experiencing a lack of support. Have you checked your spam or junk folder for these emails? If you're using Gmail, sometimes our support emails get filtered into a separate folder. If we can resolve the email issue, we'll be able to send you your personalized keys you need to embed your forms within WordPress.

Comment: @NicholasGasque - I will send you another email address in a new support ticket that can better accommodate the support issue. 

Thank you for your response.

Comment: We just responded to the new support ticket. Please let us know if you do not receive the email in the next few minutes.

Comment: Removed [tag:wordpress] because questions about  WordPress (WP, wordpress.org) are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. In the browser that you are using, please log out of Cognito Forms in any open windows or tabs, including the WordPress application of Cognito Forms. Then, log into Cognito Forms from the WordPress application and try to add the form you created to your WordPress page.

Logging in to Cognito Forms through the WordPress should generate the required keys. If the keys are still not generated, we will have to send them to you and have you enter the keys in manually.

Comment: This is the exact procedure that I initially did. To be sure, I just logged into the WP site in a different browser and followed your instruction and got the same results… No form. I'm somewhat disappointed because I have approximately 25 other forms that I need to produce, I was hoping to use your forms, but I wanted to make sure the form uploaded to the site quickly with no problems  :S … what is the procedure that I need to follow to to get the keys as of now? Thank you for your response.